# Does performSelector perform right away or is it scheduled to be performed?

Tags: objective-c

Does performSelector perform right away or is it scheduled to be performed an iota later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:)

> The `performSelector:` method is equivalent to sending an aSelector message directly to the receiver.

So it performs right away.

Also from the doc, these two messages are equivalent

```
id myClone = [anObject copy];
id myClone = [anObject performSelector:@selector(copy)];
```

and both of them will actually end to be compiled into

```
objc_msgSend(anObject, @selector(copy));
```

**EDIT**

After the discussion that originated under Anoop's answer, I think it's worth specifying that not all the variants of `performSelector:` are executed right away. There's a bunch of variants defined by `NSObject` that will cause the action to be scheduled. Moreover it's important to notice that this holds true even in case of a 0 delay, as clearly stated by the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Specifying a delay of 0 **does not necessarily cause the selector to be performed immediately**. The selector is still queued on the thread’s run loop and performed as soon as possible.

To wrap it up, here's a relevant list of variants

#### Variants with right-away execution:

- `performSelector:`
- `performSelector:withObject:`
- `performSelector:withObject:withObject:`

#### Variants whose execution is scheduled (even with 0 delay)

- `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`
- `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:`
- `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`
- `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:`
- `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`
- `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:`
- `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`

Answer (score 1):

`performSelector:`, `performSelector:withObject:` and `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` all perform right away.

You can find the doc [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a)