# What is the difference between calling the methods in iOS

Tags: objective-c

suppose i call with

```
[self methodname]
```

and other with

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodname) withObject:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

No difference whatsoever.

Straight from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:) of `performSelector:`

> The `performSelector:` method is equivalent to sending an `aSelector` message directly to the receiver. For example, all three of the following messages do the same thing:
>
> ```
> id myClone = [anObject copy];
> id myClone = [anObject performSelector:@selector(copy)];
> id myClone = [anObject performSelector:sel_getUid("copy")];
> ```

While there's no difference in the specific case, however, the reason why `performSelector:` exists is that it allows invoking an arbitrary selector that may not be available at compile time, as discussed in the doc:

> However, the `performSelector:` method allows you to send messages that aren’t determined until runtime. A variable selector can be passed as the argument:
>
> ```
> SEL myMethod = findTheAppropriateSelectorForTheCurrentSituation();
> [anObject performSelector:myMethod];
> ```

The considerations above also apply to the two variants `performSelector:withObject:`, `performSelector:withObject:withObject:`.

Please also note that this **doesn't** hold true for another set of methods, namely

- `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`
- `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:`
- `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`
- `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:`
- `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`
- `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:`
- `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`

Further info here: [Does performSelector perform right away or is it scheduled to be performed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892885/does-performselector-perform-right-away-or-is-it-scheduled-to-be-performed/15892917#15892917)

Comment: It's also worth noting that the reason the basic `performSelector:...` messages actually exist is so that you can dynamically determine which selector to use at runtime and then ask `-performSelector:` to perform it. Now that we have Obj-C blocks, passing `SELs` around is not as common, but it still has its uses (and of course backwards-compatibility).

Comment: Totally agree with the runtime information, there is obviously a compile-time difference. The compiler can provide better warnings in the first case than it can in the second. But the final runtime result is, as you say, the same.

Comment: I was in doubt whether to include that piece of information, and I decided not to, in order to keep the answer more concise. On a second though, I believe it's a sensible note, so I added a paragraph to my answer. Thanks for the constructive comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self methodname]` is shorter and easier to read, write and comprehend.

[self performSelector:@selector(methodname) withObject:nil]` makes it possible to execute arbitrary selectors. If you save the selector in a variable, then you can execute it later on without knowing the method you invoke.

//Self works like this in oops and self works as setter for your class. It also indicates that u r using getter and setter method.
```